# Text line contains an invalid character. ...^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@...... vimtex

Tags: pdf, compiling, vim

I have the following problem (see attached). Sometimes when I compile nearly everything disappears on my live-compiled file (I use `vimtex` on `Linux`). The only error I get is the following:

> Text line contains an invalid character. ...^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@......

I'm not sure if it is related to my problem, but still.

[image]

Here are my includes in preamble:

```
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  \usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
 \usepackage{subfiles}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[english]{babel}
  \usepackage{textcomp}
  \usepackage{lmodern}
  \usepackage{caption}
 \usepackage{float}
 \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
 \usepackage{blkarray}
  \usepackage{mathrsfs}
 \usepackage{pdfpages}
 \usepackage{mdframed}
 \usepackage{thmtools}
 \usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{xcolor}
 %\newmdtheoremenv{theorem}{Théorème}[section]
  %\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
 %\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemme}
  %\theoremstyle{definition}
  %\newtheorem{definition}{Définition}[section]
  %\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollaire}[theorem]
 %\newtheorem*{remark}{Remarque}
 %\newtheorem{example}{Exemple}
 %\newmdtheoremenv{property}[theorem]{Propriétés}
  \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorème}[section]
  \newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
  \newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
 \newtheorem{corollary}{Corollaire}[theorem]
  \newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemme}
  \newtheorem{property}[theorem]{Propriete}
  \newtheorem{remark}{Remarque}
  \newtheorem{example}{Exemple}
  \newtheorem{exo}{Exercice}
```

But I don't think that the problem is related to packages..

Edit: Seems like the problem appears each time I type in math mode and compile. Probably someone know the solution

I notice the following warning as well after compilation:

```
/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jknapltx/ursfs.fd|43 warning| Overfull \hbox (95.5245pt too wide) detected at line 43 /usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jknapltx/ursfs.fd|143 warning| Overfull \hbox (48.10056pt too wide)
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: This is not a *minimal* example by any means, nor a *working* one I am afraid …

Comment: As you work on making a *minimal* example that shows the problem, please remove the line numbers.  We can't copy and paste your code if it has line numbers at the beginning.

Comment: typically that means that some file got corrupted. Try to delete the auxiliary file (aux).

Comment: `^^@` is character number 0, that is ASCII NULL

Comment: @DavidCarlisle do you have a seggestion how to solve the problem, please?

Comment: The file is corrupted, back up the entire directory, then delete that file. How you corrupted the file I can not guess.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle About which file are you speaking? I don't really understand what you propose to delete. Sorry for this kind of question

Comment: The log file would show which file was being read at the point it found a NULL character. As you have shown no example nor shown the relevant part of the log, we can not know which file that is.

Comment: It was written main.aux but the thing is that it breaks not only for this main.tex but for all latex files that I use (or create new ones)

Comment: you are doing something (probably killing the tex process  while the file is open for writing) that corrupts files but hard to guess. But if it is the aux file, just remove it.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry for disturbing you, I tried to do what was proposed here but I didn't solve the problem. I observe the following warning as well. Probably it ocurs the problem: /usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jknapltx/ursfs.fd|43 warning| Overfull \hbox (95.5245pt too wide) detected at line 43
 /usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jknapltx/ursfs.fd|143 warning| Overfull \hbox (48.10056pt too wide) detected at line      143

Comment: And also the problem appears when I type in math mode. First some letters don't shot up, after text disappears

Comment: "Overvull \hbox" is a completely unrelated (and very common) warning.  Back up your tex file.  Then delete everything in that directory.  If this is happening with even a new TeX file, then make a tex file containing `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}\end{document}`, and post the resulting log file.

Comment: So I tried in a new tex file and I have no errors and still have a problem..

Comment: we can not help more, the error is not related to TeX: you are corrupting the file: replacing its content by null bytes, this is unrelated to typeseting warnings like an over-full box. It is not really possible to guess how you are doing that. Alhough as I said above I guess you are not quiting TeX or your editor correctly, so corrupting open files.